# Не понятно, как работать с JSON на C#

Tags: c#, json

Использую библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json. Получаю от сервера json такого формата:

```
{  
"count": 2,  
"rooms": [  
{  
"room_name": "room_name1",  
"names": ["user_name1", "user_name2", "user_name3"]  
},  
{  
"room_name": "room_name2",  
"names": ["user_name1", "user_name2", "user_name3"]  
}  
]
```

И я не очень понимаю как это парсить

```
JObject response = JObject.Parse(response)
```

Как мне теперь получить доступ к массиву rooms? Пытался сделать так:

```
JArray rooms_json = (JArray)response["rooms"];
```

Но элементы массива JArray - значения JValue, А у меня в json это JObject

Comment: Советую поглядеть в [документацию](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm), там есть подобный пример

Comment: @free_ze автору же надо весь json распарсить, а не какую то чать

Comment: @tym32167, в документации и про это тоже найдется информация. Конкретную ссылку я дал по сути вопроса. И ваш репорт на закрытие поддержал.